# Scala macros: finding Option's enclosed type

Tags: scala, reflection, macros, scala-macros

Given an `Option[T]` in a macro, I am trying to find the enclosed type `T`, such that given something like

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.Context

def innerTypeImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context): c.Expr[String] = {
  import c.universe._

  val tpe = weakTypeOf[T]
  val innerType = tpe.typeSymbol.asType.typeParams.head.name.decoded
  c.Expr[String] { q" {$innerType} " }
}

def innerType[T] = macro innerTypeImpl[T]
```

the call `innerType[Option[Int]]` would return `"Int"` (whereas right now it is returning `"A"`, which corresponds to the type parameter used in `Option`'s definition)

`T` may not be an `Option` (the plan was to use `tpe.typeSymbol.name.decoded == "Option"` to determine if `T` is an `Option`), so I'm not able to place any bounds on `T`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want something like this:

```
val innerType = weakTypeOf[T] match {
  case r: TypeRef => r.args.head
  case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "call this method with known type parameter only.")
}
```

Note that `WeakTypeTag` could be not a `TypeRef`.

This method will fail on `None.type`. To make it work on subtypes (like `None.type`) you should use a method `baseType` like this:

```
val innerType = weakTypeOf[T].baseType(typeOf[Option[_]].typeSymbol) match {
  case TypeRef(_, _, targ :: Nil) => targ
  case NoType => c.abort(...)
}
```

Comment: Be sure to call `baseType` prior to pattern matching. If it were possible to declare a tparamless subclass of Option, the pattern match would spuriously crash.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako: You could add details to your answer. I can't create an answer about scala macros as good as you can.

Comment: Thank you very much for elaborating! I've removed my answer, because yours is much more friendly.

Comment: Just a minor addition. If T isn't a subtype of Option, then baseType will return NoType, therefore the pattern match would look like: weakTypeOf[T].baseType(...) match { case TypeRef(_, _, targ :: Nil) => targ; case NoType => c.abort(...) }